# How to add custom button to Visual Studio Output Window toolbar

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, vs-extensibility

I'm trying to build an extension to Visual Studio with a couple of custom commands. It is well documented how to add commands to VS Menu/Toolbars. There are also many samples how to add custom button to the Project Explorer Toolbar. The problem is that best (most suitable) toolbar for my command is those on the top of Output Window.

So, there are two questions:

1. Is it possible?
2. If yes then how to achieve this?

Comment: No. The output window doesn't allow that. You could consider creating your own custom tool window...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It is really possible. It looks like any toolbar and any menu could be extended by any command.

2) The method of extending is the same for all toolbars (and menu). What you need to know is toolbar's ID. ID could be found in file vsshlids.h placed in your installed VSSDK inc folder. For output window toolbar this ID is IDM_VS_TOOL_OUTPUTWINDOW.